# Como chamar um programa executável do linux no código php?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Estou com uma duvida, tenho uma aplicação web em PHP da qual irei receber um arquivo txt. 
Preciso chamar um programa no linux que irá executar esse arquivo txt e,  gostaria de saber, como eu faria para chamar um programa do linux no codigo PHP mandando o arquivo txt que recebi?

Comment: Sua pergunta não fez sentido. Pode [edit] e buscar ser mais claro?

Comment: É isto que está procurando? http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi certo, você quer executar algum comando do Linux ou do seu SO pelo PHP. Você pode fazer isso de três formas (funções do PHP), cada uma com sua particularidade:

[exec](http://php.net/exec)

[passthru](http://php.net/passthru)

[shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec)

> É claro, existem outras funções para isso que sejam mais específicas e essas não são exclusivas para tal funcionalidade. Apenas indiquei as que acho mais adeptas à sua necessidade.